# Tool to remove JavaDoc comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is there any tool / Eclipse plugin that can remove all JavaDoc comments in a file?

The *normal* (non-JavaDoc) comments **should be intact** after running the tool.

Comment: are you talking about javadocs?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy yes javadocs.. my bad

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this regex to search replace either in eclipse / sed / your favorite editor that has regex support.

```
/\*\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

- `?s` treat input as single line
- a starting  string `\**`
- zero or more

  - negative lookahead for `*/`
  - space or non space char
- a trailing string `*/`

**Edit**

To tackle cases where strings containing javadoc, use this regex

```
((?<!\\)"([^"]|(?<=\\)")*")|(/\*\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/)
```

and replace it with first capture group

```
/1
```

Then if you say this shouldn't match

```
///** */
```

or more complex cases

I suggest, using a parser tool like antlr to parse using [java grammar for tokens like comments and strings](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g) and remove elements that you don't want

---

Sometime I find my own regex answers cryptic !!

So here is some visual feedback

```
((?!\\)"([^"]|(?=\\)")*")|(/\*\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GE_Wqc9AQTnMMKTx)

---

```
/\*\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YivhRrDio3klJXrX)

Comment: This doesn't work. It erroneously replaces sequences in strings. For example, I have a  `String s = "/**asd*/";`. It's a string, it's **not** part of a javadoc. However it got replaced.

Comment: `((?<!\\)"([^"]|(?<=\\)")*")|(/\*\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/)` matches ordinary strings! It killed all my strings.

Comment: You should be able to use something like `^[^"]*/\*\*` to match the starts of javadoc comments without matching anything in a string.

Comment: @Pacerier yes, it does match strings but as you are replace it with capture group 1 , it(string) will get replaced with itself !

Comment: @PrashantBhate Oh for the eclipse editor it should have been `\1` instead of `/1`. I'll take this as answer until someone else has a solution which doesn't fall in cases like these `///**test*/`, thanks!

Comment: @PrashantBhate  sed doesnt support lookahead nor non-capturing groups so that regex wont compile.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Prashant Bhate didn't work for me in eclipse ide:

```
/\*\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

I had to use

```
/\*/*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

instead.

Comment: This matches normal comments

Answer (score 2):

I made a open source [library](https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/CommentRemover) for this purpose , its called CommentRemover you can remove single line and multiple line Java Comments.

It supports remove or NOT remove TODO's.
Also it supports JavaScript , HTML , CSS , Properties , JSP and XML Comments too.

Little code snippet how to use it(There is 2 type usage):

First way InternalPath

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws CommentRemoverException {

 // root dir is: /Users/user/Projects/MyProject
 // example for startInternalPath

 CommentRemover commentRemover = new CommentRemover.CommentRemoverBuilder()
        .removeJava(true) // Remove Java file Comments....
        .removeJavaScript(true) // Remove JavaScript file Comments....
        .removeJSP(true) // etc.. goes like that
        .removeTodos(false) //  Do Not Touch Todos (leave them alone)
        .removeSingleLines(true) // Remove single line type comments
        .removeMultiLines(true) // Remove multiple type comments
        .startInternalPath("src.main.app") // Starts from {rootDir}/src/main/app , leave it empty string when you want to start from root dir
        .setExcludePackages(new String[]{"src.main.java.app.pattern"}) // Refers to {rootDir}/src/main/java/app/pattern and skips this directory
        .build();

 CommentProcessor commentProcessor = new CommentProcessor(commentRemover);
                  commentProcessor.start();        
  }
```

Second way ExternalPath

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws CommentRemoverException {

 // example for externalInternalPath

 CommentRemover commentRemover = new CommentRemover.CommentRemoverBuilder()
        .removeJava(true) // Remove Java file Comments....
        .removeJavaScript(true) // Remove JavaScript file Comments....
        .removeJSP(true) // etc..
        .removeTodos(true) // Remove todos
        .removeSingleLines(false) // Do not remove single line type comments
        .removeMultiLines(true) // Remove multiple type comments
        .startExternalPath("/Users/user/Projects/MyOtherProject")// Give it full path for external directories
        .setExcludePackages(new String[]{"src.main.java.model"}) // Refers to /Users/user/Projects/MyOtherProject/src/main/java/model and skips this directory.
        .build();

 CommentProcessor commentProcessor = new CommentProcessor(commentRemover);
                  commentProcessor.start();        
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, great tool!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in vim:

```
/\/\*\*\_.\{-}\*\/
```

The `\_.\{-}` pattern matches any character (`.`), including the newline (`\_`), as few as possible (`\{-}`).

This matches against multi-line Javadoc comments such as:

```
/**
 * My Javadoc comment here
 */
```

But will not match against comments such as:

```
// My non-Javadoc comment
```

Comment: String `/\/\*\*\_.\{-}\*\/`only does the search. In command mode write `:%s/\s\+\/\*\*\_.\{-}\*\///g` to replace all Javadocs, including leading whitespaces.