# Removing all types of comments in java file

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

I have a java project and i have used comments in many location in various java files in the project. Now i need to remove all type of comments : single line , multiple line comments . 
Please provide automation for removing comments. using tools or in eclipse etc.

Currently i am manually trying to remove all commetns

Comment: Why would you want to remove comments?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078528/tool-to-remove-javadoc-comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool to remove JavaDoc comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078528/tool-to-remove-javadoc-comments)

Answer (score 7):

You can remove all single- or multi-line block comments (but not line comments with `//`) by searching for the following regular expression in your project(s)/file(s) and replacing by `$1`:

`^([^"\r\n]*?(?:(?<=')"[^"\r\n]*?|(?<!')"[^"\r\n]*?"[^"\r\n]*?)*?)(?<!/)/\*[^\*]*(?:\*+[^/][^\*]*)*?\*+/`

It's possible that you have to execute it more than once.

This regular expression avoids the following pitfalls:

1. Code between two comments `/* Comment 1 */ foo(); /* Comment 2 */`
2. Line comments starting with an asterisk: `//***NOTE***`
3. Comment delimiters inside string literals: `stringbuilder.append("/*");`; also if there is a double quote inside single quotes before the comment

To remove all single-line comments, search for the following regular expression in your project(s)/file(s) and replace by `$1`:

`^([^"\r\n]*?(?:(?<=')"[^"\r\n]*?|(?<!')"[^"\r\n]*?"[^"\r\n]*?)*?)\s*//[^\r\n]*`

This regular expression also avoids comment delimiters inside double quotes, but does NOT check for multi-line comments, so `/* // */` will be incorrectly removed.

Answer (score 3):

I had to write somehting to do this a few weeks ago. This should handle all comments, nested or otherwise. It is long, but I haven't seen a regex version that handled nested comments properly. I didn't have to preserve javadoc, but I presume you do, so I added some code that I belive should handle that. I also added code to support the \r\n and \r line separators. The new code is marked as such.

```
public static String removeComments(String code) {
    StringBuilder newCode = new StringBuilder();
    try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(code)) {
        boolean inBlockComment = false;
        boolean inLineComment = false;
        boolean out = true;

        int prev = sr.read();
        int cur;
        for(cur = sr.read(); cur != -1; cur = sr.read()) {
            if(inBlockComment) {
                if (prev == '*' && cur == '/') {
                    inBlockComment = false;
                    out = false;
                }
            } else if (inLineComment) {
                if (cur == '\r') { // start untested block
                    sr.mark(1);
                    int next = sr.read();
                    if (next != '\n') {
                        sr.reset();
                    }
                    inLineComment = false;
                    out = false; // end untested block
                } else if (cur == '\n') {
                    inLineComment = false;
                    out = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (prev == '/' && cur == '*') {
                    sr.mark(1); // start untested block
                    int next = sr.read();
                    if (next != '*') {
                        inBlockComment = true; // tested line (without rest of block)
                    }
                    sr.reset(); // end untested block
                } else if (prev == '/' && cur == '/') {
                    inLineComment = true;
                } else if (out){
                    newCode.append((char)prev);
                } else {
                    out = true;
                }
            }
            prev = cur;
        }
        if (prev != -1 && out && !inLineComment) {
            newCode.append((char)prev);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newCode.toString();
}
```

Comment: Should modify if (prev == '/' && cur == '*') to if ((prev == '/' && cur == '*') || prev == '*' && cur == '*') to support comments in the form of /**

Comment: You still got a bug in there. If a comment read something like `/*// Hi */` it will not be removed properly

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Why do you say that? Block comments have precedent over line comments in the code so it will still end the comment at the */.

Comment: @AndrewVitkus
I applied it to a big source code and it didn't work correctly for those cases apparently, that's all

Comment: It doesn't work if comments are in this format /** */, I replaced all /** to /* in string before calling this proc

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but this may help someone who enjoys working on command line like myself:

The `perl` one-liner below will remove all comments:

```
perl -0pe 's|//.*?\n|\n|g; s#/\*(.|\n)*?\*/##g;' test.java
```

Example:

```
cat test.java
this is a test

/**
*This should be removed
*This should be removed
*/

this should not be removed

//this should be removed

this should not be removed

this should not be removed //this should be removed
```

Output:

```
perl -0pe 's#/\*\*(.|\n)*?\*/##g; s|//.*?\n|\n|g' test.java
this is a test



this should not be removed



this should not be removed

this should not be removed
```

If you want get rid of multiple blank lines as well:

```
perl -0pe 's|//.*?\n|\n|g; s#/\*(.|\n)*?\*/##g; s/\n\n+/\n\n/g' test.java
this is a test

this should not be removed

this should not be removed

this should not be removed
```

**EDIT:** Corrected regex

Comment: Works a charm and is quick!

Comment: This would replace `https://example.com` with `https:`

Answer (score 2):

you can try it with the java-comment-preprocessor:

```
java -jar ./jcp-6.0.0.jar --i:/sourceFolder --o:/resultFolder -ef:none --r
```

[source](https://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/#OMG!_It_allows_to_remove_all_your_comments!)

Comment: I have tried this project. I noticed that once it removes a Java `//` comment, if the comment was for the whole line (maybe with some white spaces or tabs before it), it does not remove the line, which would have been nice.... I could not find an option for this. Also, it does not know to remove (XML/SQL) comments from XML/SQL files....

Answer (score 2):

I made a open source [library](https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/CommentRemover) and uploaded to github, its called CommentRemover you can remove single line and multiple line Java Comments.

It supports remove or NOT remove TODO's.
Also it supports JavaScript , HTML , CSS , Properties , JSP and XML Comments too.

There is a little code snippet how to use it (There is 2 type usage):

First way InternalPath

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws CommentRemoverException {

 // root dir is: /Users/user/Projects/MyProject
 // example for startInternalPath

 CommentRemover commentRemover = new CommentRemover.CommentRemoverBuilder()
        .removeJava(true) // Remove Java file Comments....
        .removeJavaScript(true) // Remove JavaScript file Comments....
        .removeJSP(true) // etc.. goes like that
        .removeTodos(false) //  Do Not Touch Todos (leave them alone)
        .removeSingleLines(true) // Remove single line type comments
        .removeMultiLines(true) // Remove multiple type comments
        .startInternalPath("src.main.app") // Starts from {rootDir}/src/main/app , leave it empty string when you want to start from root dir
        .setExcludePackages(new String[]{"src.main.java.app.pattern"}) // Refers to {rootDir}/src/main/java/app/pattern and skips this directory
        .build();

 CommentProcessor commentProcessor = new CommentProcessor(commentRemover);
                  commentProcessor.start();        
  }
```

Second way ExternalPath

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws CommentRemoverException {

 // example for externalInternalPath

 CommentRemover commentRemover = new CommentRemover.CommentRemoverBuilder()
        .removeJava(true) // Remove Java file Comments....
        .removeJavaScript(true) // Remove JavaScript file Comments....
        .removeJSP(true) // etc..
        .removeTodos(true) // Remove todos
        .removeSingleLines(false) // Do not remove single line type comments
        .removeMultiLines(true) // Remove multiple type comments
        .startExternalPath("/Users/user/Projects/MyOtherProject")// Give it full path for external directories
        .setExcludePackages(new String[]{"src.main.java.model"}) // Refers to /Users/user/Projects/MyOtherProject/src/main/java/model and skips this directory.
        .build();

 CommentProcessor commentProcessor = new CommentProcessor(commentRemover);
                  commentProcessor.start();        
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with source code is hard unless you know more on the writing of comment.
In the more general case, you could have // or /* in text constants. So your **really** need to parse the file at a syntaxic level, not only lexical. IMHO the only bulletproof solution would be to start for example with the java parser from [openjdk](http://openjdk.java.net/).

If you know that your comments are never deeply mixed with the code (in my exemple comments **MUST** be full lines), a python script could help

```
multiple = False
for line in text:
    stripped = line.strip()
    if multiple:
        if stripped.endswith('*/'):
            multiple = False
            continue
    elif stripped.startswith('/*'):
        multiple = True
    elif stripped.startswith('//'):
        pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

Comment: **BEWARE** : the script is far from complete and totally untested. As others said, it is certainly a **very bad** idea to remove all comments including copyright notices ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse IDE, you could make regex do the work for you.

Open the search window (Ctrl+F), and check 'Regular Expression'.

Provide the expression as
`/\*\*(?s:(?!\*/).)*\*/`

Prasanth Bhate has explained it in [Tool to remove JavaDoc comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078528/tool-to-remove-javadoc-comments)

Answer (score 1):

public class TestForStrings {

```
/**
 * The main method.
 *
 * @param args
 *            the arguments
 * @throws Exception
 *             the exception
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String[] imports = new String[100];
    String fileName = "Menu.java";
    // This will reference one API at a time
    String line = null;
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        int startingOffset = 0;

        // This will reference one API at a time

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

        // remove single line comments
        for (int count = 0; count < lines.size(); count++) {
            String tempString = lines.get(count);

            lines.set(count, removeSingleLineComment(tempString));

        }
        // remove multiple lines comment
        for (int count = 0; count < lines.size(); count++) {
            String tempString = lines.get(count);

            removeMultipleLineComment(tempString, count, lines);
        }

        for (int count = 0; count < lines.size(); count++) {
            System.out.println(lines.get(count));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

/**
 * Removes the multiple line comment.
 *
 * @param tempString
 *            the temp string
 * @param count
 *            the count
 * @param lines
 *            the lines
 * @return the string
 */
private static List<String> removeMultipleLineComment(String tempString,
        int count, List<String> lines) {
    try {
        if (tempString.contains("/**") || (tempString.contains("/*"))) {
            int StartIndex = count;
            while (!(lines.get(count).contains("*/") || lines.get(count)
                    .contains("**/"))) {
                count++;
            }
            int endIndex = ++count;
            if (StartIndex != endIndex) {
                while (StartIndex != endIndex) {
                    lines.set(StartIndex, "");
                    StartIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    return lines;
}

/**
 * Remove single line comments .
 *
 * @param line
 *            the line
 * @return the string
 * @throws Exception
 *             the exception
 */

private static String removeSingleLineComment(String line) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (line.contains(("//"))) {
            int startIndex = line.indexOf("//");
            int endIndex = line.length();
            String tempoString = line.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            line = line.replace(tempoString, "");
        }
        if ((line.contains("/*") || line.contains("/**"))
                && (line.contains("**/") || line.contains("*/"))) {
            int startIndex = line.indexOf("/**");
            int endIndex = line.length();
            String tempoString = line.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

            line = line.replace(tempoString, "");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    return line;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with yesterday. 
This is actually homework I got from school so if anybody reads this and finds a bug before I turn it in, please leave a comment =)

ps. 'FilterState' is a enum class

```
public static String deleteComments(String javaCode) {
    FilterState state = FilterState.IN_CODE;

    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

    char prevC=' ';
    for(int i = 0; i<javaCode.length(); i++){
        char c = javaCode.charAt(i);
        switch(state){
            case IN_CODE:
                if(c=='/')
                    state = FilterState.CAN_BE_COMMENT_START;
                else {
                    if (c == '"')
                        state = FilterState.INSIDE_STRING;
                    strB.append(c);
                }
                break;
            case CAN_BE_COMMENT_START:
                if(c=='*'){
                    state = FilterState.IN_COMMENT_BLOCK;
                }
                else if(c=='/'){
                    state = FilterState.ON_COMMENT_LINE;
                }
                else {
                    state = FilterState.IN_CODE;
                    strB.append(prevC+c);
                }
                break;
            case ON_COMMENT_LINE:
                if(c=='\n' || c=='\r') {
                    state = FilterState.IN_CODE;
                    strB.append(c);
                }
                break;
            case IN_COMMENT_BLOCK:
                if(c=='*')
                    state=FilterState.CAN_BE_COMMENT_END;
                break;
            case CAN_BE_COMMENT_END:
                if(c=='/')
                    state = FilterState.IN_CODE;
                else if(c!='*')
                    state = FilterState.IN_COMMENT_BLOCK;
                break;
            case INSIDE_STRING:
                if(c == '"' && prevC!='\\')
                    state = FilterState.IN_CODE;
                strB.append(c);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("unknown case");
                return null;
        }
        prevC = c;
    }
    return strB.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static int find(String s, String t, int start) {
    int ret = s.indexOf(t, start);
    return ret < 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : ret;
}
private static int findSkipEsc(String s, String t, int start) {
    while(true) {
        int ret = find(s, t, start);
        if( ret == Integer.MAX_VALUE) return -1;
        int esc = find(s, "\\", start);
        if( esc > ret) return ret;
        start += 2;
    }
}

private static String removeLineCommnt(String s) {
    int i, start = 0;
    while (0 <= (i = find(s, "//", start))) { //Speed it up
        int j = find(s, "'", start);
        int k = find(s, "\"", start);
        int first = min(i, min(j, k));
        if (first == Integer.MAX_VALUE) return s;
        if (i == first) return s.substring(0, i);
        //skipp quoted string
        start = first+1;
        if (k == first) { // " asdas\"dasd "
            start = findSkipEsc(s,"\"",start);
            if (start < 0) return s;
            start++;
            continue;
        }
        //if j == first ' asda\'sasd ' --- not in JSON
        start = findSkipEsc(s,"'\"'",start);
        if (start < 0) return s;
        start++;
    }
    return s;
}

static String removeLineCommnts(String s) {
    if (!s.contains("//")) return s; //Speed it up
    return Arrays.stream(s.split("[\\n\\r]+")).
            map(Common::removeLineCommnt).
            collect(Collectors.joining("\n")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew-Vitkus 's answer was pretty close, but had some bugs (removing the character before /, for example  dd/mm/yyyy became d/m/yyyy) but here's the cleaner version which RETAINS THE NUMBER OF LINES in the source file.

```
public static String removeComments(String code) {

    StringBuilder cc = new StringBuilder();

    try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(code)) {

        boolean inBlockComment = false;
        boolean inLineComment = false;
        boolean out = true;

        int prev = sr.read();
        int cur;
    
        for(cur = sr.read(); cur != -1; cur = sr.read()) {

            if(inBlockComment) {
                if (prev == '*' && cur == '/') {
                    inBlockComment = false;
                    out = false;
                } else if (cur == '\r' || cur == '\n') {
                    //keep these to retain line breaks
                    cc.append((char)cur);
                }
            } else if (inLineComment) {
                if (cur == '\n') {
                    if (prev == '\r'){
                        cc.append('\r');
                    }
                    inLineComment = false;
                    out = true; //allows \n to be added
                }
            } else {
                if (cur == '/'){
                    sr.mark(1); // start untested block
                    int next = sr.read();
                    if (next == '*') {
                        inBlockComment = true; 
                    } else if (next == '/'){
                        inLineComment = true; 
                    }
                    sr.reset(); // end untested block

                    cc.append((char)prev);//add this char in all cases

                } else if (out){
                    cc.append((char)prev);
                } else {
                    out = true;
                }
            }
            prev = cur;
        }
    
        if (prev != -1 && out && !inLineComment && !inBlockComment) {
            cc.append((char)prev);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cc.toString();
}
```