# Is there a way to auto-collapse copyright comments in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Any project created by Google has a big fat copyright comment block at the top of every file. This just gets in the way and makes comprehending the code more difficult. You can collapse it but it'll be expanded again the next time you open the project. I end up deleting every one I see.

Is there a plugin or setting I can use to simply auto-collapse the copyright comment blocks?

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: Take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/525974/how-to-remove-comments-from-an-xml-file

Comment: It's in every .java file as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333031/removing-all-types-of-comments-in-java-file/32977808#:~:text=Open%20the%20search%20window%20(Ctrl,and%20check%20'Regular%20Expression'.&text=Prasanth%20Bhate%20has%20explained%20it%20in%20Tool%20to%20remove%20JavaDoc%20comments%3F&text=I%20made%20a%20open%20source,remove%20or%20NOT%20remove%20TODO's.

Comment: I don't know any way to hide them.May be someone else can help here :)